# GoogleFinance for Price Open on a specific date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I can only get a price open for a stock on the latest trade day?

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BB","priceopen")
```

However, adding a date returns #NA.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BB","priceopen", "2020/12/17")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every day the open price will close,  so if you want to know the past value for some date use:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BB", "close", "2020/12/17")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use "open" instead of "priceopen".